# Batch file: List all folders in current directory with number/counter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Sorry for bad description, i am expecting the following output:

1. FolderA
2. FolderB
3. FolderC

The following code does not work for me

```
@ECHO OFF
set /a count=0

for /d %%d in (*) do (
set  /a count+=1
@echo %count%. %%d 
)
PAUSE
```

The counter stays at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is delayed variable expansion. For that, simply make the following 2 changes:

1. Add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to the top of your command file.
2. Replace `%count%` with `!count!`.

The result is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0

for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set /a count+=1
    @echo !count!. %%d 
)
pause
```