# Write batch file to count folders inside main folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I am new to this, i am trying to write a batch file to calculate number of folders inside folder. Can someone please help me?

Here is folder system:
I have hundreds of folders like:

```
Area1
Area2
Area3
....
```

Inside each of above folder there is one folder named "Zone".
What i am trying to find is number of folders inside Zone folder for each Area1, Area2... so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9459870/1175253

Comment: @Sam - I understood how it is counting folders inside folder. But how should we point to particular folder path?

Comment: `pushd "main_dir"`

`<the linked script>`

`popd`

Comment: @Sam - I tried this but not working? echo off
pushd C:\Users\KANWAR\Desktop\Test
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0

for /d %%d in (*) do (
 for /Zone %%d in (*) do(
    set /a count+=1
    echo !count!. %%d  
 ) 
)
pause

Answer (score 0):

start one folder above the AREAx folders:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /d %%i in (*.*) do (
    pushd %%i\ZONE
    set /a count=0
    for /d %%j in (*.*) do set /a count+=1
    popd
    call echo %%count%% folder(s^) in %%i\ZONE
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR /f %%i IN ('dir /b/ad area*') DO (
 IF EXIST ".\%%i\zone\." (
  FOR /f %%c IN (' DIR /ad ".\%%i\zone\"') DO SET /a count=%%c-2 2>nul
  ECHO ".\%%i\zone" : !count! directories
  ) ELSE (ECHO ".\%%i\zone" does NOT EXIST
 )
)
```